# creating hyperlinks based on the value of 1 cells validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I am working on a report where i have a list of projects in lets assume Column A.
In column B the only values would be either Yes or No.

Based on the values in column B, if "Yes" i want cell B2 with "Yes" hyperlinked, where that hyperlink takes us to tab "project 1" cell A1.

Or the second condition that can work is that if the value in B2 is "Yes" the A2 (Project name) is hyperlinked taking it to tab "project 1 Cell A1?

[image: example scenario]

Comment: Is status (Yes/No) column calculated or manually entered? If it's calculated than you can easily complete it with `HYPERLINK` function to work as you need, however if it's manually entered, then you probably need to use macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link in column A: `=IF(B2="Yes"; HYPERLINK("#"& A2 &"!$A$1"; "Project " & Row()-1); "Project " & Row()-1)`
Make the link in column B: `=IF("placeInputHere"="Yes"; HYPERLINK("#"& A2 &"!$A$1"; "Yes"; "No")`

For the column A version, no input needed - just enter it in A2 and drag down for as many project sheets as you have (under the assumption that they all follow the naming convention you have shown in the screenshot!).

Resources:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hyperlinks-in-worksheets-edb15706-517b-4ecf-81c6-84068ff8677e#__toc305068125
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/15/excel-insert-hyperlink/#hyperlink-function